# Display Matrix in Quarto for docx rendering

Tags: matrix, docx, quarto

I've been trying to displayed an equation in Quarto in the form of matrix and rendering it to docx, but I found difficulty on it.

From multiple sources, the matrix (3x3) code represented as

```
\matrix(@@&&)
###Example
a= [\matrix(2&1&5@6&7&9@8&3&0)]
```

[image]
with '@' for separation of row and '&' for separation of column.
How do I display matrix in Quarto to docx rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
---
title: "Matrix equation"
format: docx
editor: visual
---

# Matrix equation

$$a = \begin{bmatrix}
   2 & 1 & 5 \\
   6 & 7 & 9 \\
   8 & 3 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}$$
```

This is a screenshot of the final result rendering to docx:

[image]

If you want more information about inserting matrices check out [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Matrices). I think your problem is with LaTeX.